# Eclipse CDT not adding to Includes path

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have several projects for libraries and processes cross compiling for arm. But in one project, I have the problem with unresolved inclusions (It is compiling fine). I checked 
`Properties > C++ General > Paths and Symbols` and 
`C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > Includes` but my include path does not show up in the `Includes` (see picture, its missing my `/workspace/include` path)

[Missing includes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtZlU.png)

Comment: What type of project do you have - makefile? managed build? In some project types, you need to add the include paths manually.